# unable to retrieve data from wso2 das server 3.0.1 and apim 1.10

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I configured wso2 das 3.0.1 and apim 1.10 using REST client and trying to search data from das server by following below url:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Searching+Data+By+Categories

In soap ui i have given below:

method: POST

Endpoint: https://localhost:9446 (my das is running on 9446 port)

Resource: /analytics/drilldown

data: 
    {

```
     "api": "CaluclatorAPI",
     "query" : "timestamp : [1489393816 to 1489393843]",
        "recordStart" : 0,
        "recordCount" : 100
}
```

Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= (admin:admin changed to base64)

i'm getting below error:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 09:08:50 GMT
Expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it. by using below:

Resource: /analytics/search

POST :

{

```
     "tableName": "org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_response",
      "start":0, 
    "count":100
```

}